# finding strings that appear in one column but missing from another based on a list of strings

Tags: r, string, dataframe, multiple-columns, grepl

I have a df, data:

```
data = data.frame("text" = c("John met Jay who met Jack who met Josh who met Jamie", "John and Jay and Jack and Josh and Jamie"), 
"names.in.text" = c("Jay; Jack; Josh; Jamie", "John; Jack; Josh; Jamie"), 
"missing.names" = c("",""))

> data
                                    text             names.in.text            missing.names
1 John met Jay who met Jack who met Josh who met Jamie  Jay; Jack; Josh; Jamie              
2             John and Jay and Jack and Josh and Jamie John; Jack; Josh; Jamie
```

and a second df of names:

```
names = data.frame("names" = c("John", "Jay", "Jack", "Josh", "Jamie"))
> names
  names
1  John
2   Jay
3  Jack
4  Josh
5 Jamie
```

I am trying to find out whether data$names.in.text contains all the names contained in data$text. The universe of names is in names$names. Ideally, for each row of data$missing, I'd like to know which names$names is missing from data$names.in.text:

```
                                                  text           names.in.text missing.names
1 John met Jay who met Jack who met Josh who met Jamie  Jay; Jack; Josh; Jamie          John
2             John and Jay and Jack and Josh and Jamie John; Jack; Josh; Jamie           Jay
```

Or any other configuration that would easily tell me what names are in the text but missing from names.in.text

So essentially I am looking to find what names$names are included in data$text but not data$names.in.text, and then list those names in data$missing.names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `tidyverse` solution:

```r
library(tidyverse)

data %>%
  mutate(missing.names = map2_chr(text, str_split(names.in.text, '; '),
                                  ~ str_c(str_extract_all(.x, regex(str_c(setdiff(names$names, .y), collapse = '|')))[[1]], collapse = '; ')))

# # A tibble: 2 × 3
#   text                                                 names.in.text           missing.names
#   <chr>                                                <chr>                   <chr>        
# 1 John met Jay who met Jack who met Josh who met Jamie Jay; Jack; Josh; Jamie  John         
# 2 John and Jay and Jack and Josh and Jamie             John; Jack; Josh; Jamie Jay
```

Comment: Fabulous solution!

Comment: This works - thank you! How can I tweak it so that each names$names gets tested in all of the following ways (to avoid names that can be part of longer words):
 Josh (space before and after)
 Josh, (space before)
 Josh. (space before)

Comment: @user17661126 Sorry that I don't understand what you mean. Could you give me an example data?

Comment: All set - I came up with an ugly but functional solution using your code:

paste0(str_c(setdiff(names$names, .y), collapse = ' | '), str_c(setdiff(names$names, .y), collapse = ',| '), str_c(setdiff(names$names, .y), collapse = '\\.| '))))[[1]]), collapse = '; ')

within the regex() of your code

Answer (score 1):

A **base R** approach using `apply`/`sapply`. I extended the first text and *names* by "JJ" to show more than one name in missing.

```
data$missing.names <- apply(sapply(names$names, function(nms) 
  grepl(paste0("\\b",nms,"\\b"), data$text) & 
    !grepl(nms, data$names.in.text)), 1, function(x) 
  paste(names$names[x], collapse=", "))

data
                                                     text
1 John met Jay who met Jack who met Josh who met Jamie JJ
2                John and Jay and Jack and Josh and Jamie
            names.in.text missing.names
1  Jay; Jack; Josh; Jamie      John, JJ
2 John; Jack; Josh; Jamie           Jay
```

##### Data

```
data <- structure(list(text = c("John met Jay who met Jack who met Josh who met Jamie JJ", 
"John and Jay and Jack and Josh and Jamie"), names.in.text = c("Jay; Jack; Josh; Jamie", 
"John; Jack; Josh; Jamie")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))

names <- structure(list(names = c("John", "Jay", "Jack", "Josh", "Jamie", 
"JJ")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but I think the solution doesn't look back to data$text to see what names it contains that are missing from data$names.in.text - instead it isolates the names from names$names that are not in data$names.in.text.

Comment: Sorry, I might not have been cleared. I'm trying to verify that names.in.text has captured all the possible unique names in data$text. The world of possible names is names$names. So I need to find the names$names that are not in data$names.in.text, and then see if any of those names appear in data$text, and if so update data$missing.names accordingly.